# Business Central FLF licensing key generation

Tags: license-key, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-365-ce-onpremises

My colleague, who raises BC Licences has been asked to create a BC V20 FLF licence for an On-Prem installation containing a list of specific ID's all in the customization range 50000 to 99999. However, he has reported: 'I do not control or enter anything to do with permissions in the FLF so cannot influence it in any way'. My only option is to add the third party app from the drop down and include isv.

I've added a screenshot of the licence tool below. Where would one specify ID's to include and their permissions?

[image: BC Licence tool]

Answer (score 0):

On the customer summary your colleague would have selected option 1 below (sorry for the danish).
[image]

In order to assign objects in customization range (50000-99999) your colleague would need to select option 2 which would lead to this screen:
[image]

Once the objects have been assigned you need to go back to the first screen and export the license again.